# Why do I get this error when using OpenCV? error: undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, highgui

I'm trying to run a simple code using openCV but I keep getting this errors.

> error: undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'
>
> error: undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame'
>
> error: undefined reference to `cvReleaseCapture'

As far as I know these functions are defined in 'highgui' component which I included it's header to my code and also included it's path to my library paths.

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
```

I successfully used other functions of 'highgui' component without any error. ex: 'cvLoadImage'
Also my IDE's intellisense keeps suggesting these functions to me which I think it means that I had included the library path correctly.

Why am I getting these errors?

for more information I'm using openCV 3.0.0, Qt creator 3.1.1 on linux mint 17.2

the full simple code I'm trying to run is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("/home/ali/drop.avi");
    cvNamedWindow("t2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1) 
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frame) break;
        cvShowImage("t2",frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if(c==27) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("t2");

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the code above is from opencv's deprecated c-api, you **must not** use it. instead use cv::Mat, cv::VideoCapture, the c++ api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source of study for openCV is outdated. That is the old C api. Study some of the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/)

EDIT: Also, follow the advice from @berak to use cv::Mat and cv::VideoCapture

Replace `<cv.h>` with `<opencv2/core.hpp>`

And with my openCV installation, I include highgui like this `<opencv2/highgui.hpp>`

Comment: I think the post deals with linker errors, how replacing headers will help?

Comment: Linker errors to outdated API functions... They may have been changed or removed entirely. Switch to C++ API